# Programmatically determine if git-flow is initialized

Tags: git-flow

Is there any way to do this?  Is the repo considered initialized if it simply has the git-flow directives in `.git/config` like

```
....
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag = v
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Answered here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitflow-users/7HzYr2JsJT0).  Basically:

1. Check config for gitflow.branch.master and if the branch does exist in the repo
2. Check config for gitflow.branch.develop and if the branch does exist in the repo
3. Master branch can not be the same as develop branch.
4. Make sure all the prefixes are configured.

Answer (score 3):

What I do to check is I run following command:
`git flow config >/dev/null 2>&1`. If it is initialized, then it exits with `0` otherwise with `1`.

I usually do something like this:

```
if $(git flow config >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
    echo initialized
else
    echo not initialized
    git flow init -d
fi
```

I some time short it like:
`git flow config >/dev/null 2>&1 || git flow init -d`